# Python3: How to loop my dice roller program back to the start

Tags: python-3.x, restart

Writing my first solo program with no help from teacher or group, a simple code that can act as a D&D dice roller for any type or number of dice a user requires.

I've been working on it for about four hours, and I'm stuck on the last thing I want to do which is loop it back to the beginning instead of just ending when a user doesn't reroll the already chosen dice, I'd like it so it starts again from the top so the player can input a new dice value and number of rolls generated without closing the program and rerunning it.

```
import random

try:
    min = 1
    max = int(input("Enter the highest value of dice to be rolled: "))
except:
    print("Your input was invalid, program rolled a d20 by default")
    min = 1
    max = 20

again = True
number_of_dice = int(input("Enter number of dice to roll: "))

for i in range(number_of_dice - 1):
    print(random.randint(min, max))

while again:
    print(random.randint(min, max))

    reroll = input("Roll again? (y/n): ")

    if reroll.lower() == "y" or reroll.lower() == "yes":
        for i in range(number_of_dice - 1):
            print(random.randint(min, max))
    else:
        print("Thank you")
        break
```

Comment: Look into functions... You will also need another `while` loop with a different user input to say wether to end the program or not.

Comment: you can put the whole thing into a while(1) loop, which is going to loop endlessley, and put a suitable break criteria inside..

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like:

```
import random
    
while True:

    try:
        min = 1
        max = int(input("Enter the highest value of dice to be rolled or 0 to exit: "))
    except:
        print("Your input was invalid, program rolled a d20 by default")
        min = 1
        max = 20

    if max == 0:
        break
    if max < 0:
        continue
    
    again = True
    number_of_dice = int(input("Enter number of dice to roll: "))
    
    

    for i in range(number_of_dice - 1):
        print(random.randint(min, max))
    
    while again:
        print(random.randint(min, max))
    
        reroll = input("Roll again? (y/n): ")
    
        if reroll.lower() == "y" or reroll.lower() == "yes":
            for i in range(number_of_dice - 1):
                print(random.randint(min, max))
        else:
            print("Thank you")
            break
```

Also, I would suggest renaming "min" and "max" as they are reserved keywords

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of putting the whole program in a while True loop. It's much more elegant than the solutions that I was trying to work out in my head. Have a great day!